# Is Industry or PhD programs best for someone wanting to go to quantum machine learning?

Tags: resource-request, machine-learning, research

Is Industry and the companies including IBMa and D-wave etc or PhD research programs best for someone wanting to go to quantum statistical/mathematical machine learning in the United States?

I mean actual quantum computers rather than simulation of quantum computers on classical computers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a graduate MS student right now and unless you go to Caltech, MIT, or Waterloo it’s going to be really hard for you to get experience at industry without attending a PhD in quantum information and computation

Comment: How about a PhD in data science? But the problem with that is data science is a narrow field that’s niche and done on classical computers. Look at NYU etc. will I be able to easily learn quantum computing after getting a degree that makes me forced to work on classical computers? I’ll have spent my entire time up to finishing a PhD in classical computing which is already no longer the cutting edge.

Comment: I think it is important to realize that the field of quantum computing will (highly, highly likely) never make classical computing obsolete. So there is still a lot of 'cutting edge' research possible in classical computer science. Data science is about the most popular field in industry from a software engineering perspective, whereas quantum computing is much more selective and its demand is much, much smaller. Data science will be here for quite some time, and if you are in the long term interested in making a career in industry than it is a very good orientation (for a PhD or reschooling).